# extending a non-code (Varien) class in Magento located in lib - Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql

Tags: extensions, magento-1.4, php-pdo

I have extended classes from core in Magento before, but am uncertain how to extend this class:

```
Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
//located in lib/Varien/Db/Adappter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

How would I do this?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860858/magento-rewrite-lib-file/14861227#14861227

Answer (score 1):

If by extending you mean override them, then the answer is: you can't. There is no way to do a rewrite in your own extension for a `lib` class. Well, there is one way to do that. You can make a copy of the file in the `app/code` folder.

So for this file: `lib/Varien/Db/Adappter/Pdo/Mysql.php`, you could make a copy of that file in `app/code/local/Varien/Db/Adappter/Pdo/Mysql.php` to override the class.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I create a class in lib/Exemple/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
with extend Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql

```
class Exemple_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
```

And I changed the adapter in config file

app/etc/config.xml

```
<resource>
    <connection>
        <types>
            <pdo_mysql>
                <adapter>Exemple_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql</adapter>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql</class>
                <compatibleMode>1</compatibleMode>
             </pdo_mysql>
        </types>        
    </connection>        
</resource>
```

Because you have in lib

lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql implements Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface
```

and in lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
class Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
```